# Extracting just date from returned date and time by SQL server to show in web pages

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, date

I retrieve the date from sql server and want to display the date as "November 20, 2014" in my view / web page. The problem is SQL server returned the date and time (12/3/2014 12:00:00 AM). Below is my controller action and view

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            NewsViewModel NewsVM = new NewsViewModel(); //Initializing the view model
            var news = db.WASA_News.ToList();// getting all news from database
            NewsVM.WasaNews = news; //Adding the news into the viewmodel

            return View(NewsVM);// Returning ViewNodel
        }
```

Partial View

```
<div class="col-md-9 animated fadeInLeft">
                      <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Date)</span>
                      <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Title)</span>
                      <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Description)</p>
 </div>
```

any help regarding the extracting the date on desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to format the date. `<span>@Model.item.News_Date.ToString("d")</span>` should format the date only.

If you can edit your model, you can alternatively add the DisplayFormat attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime News_Date { get; set; }
```

And if you want to stick with the Html helper method, you can use the Value helper.

```
@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => modelItem.News_Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
```

Comment: i just tried this but, there is an error "No overload for method ToString takes 1 argument"

Comment: What type if News_Date? DateTime or DateTime? (nullable)?

Comment: If nullable, then you have to get the value, so something like this should work: `@(Model.News_Date.HasValue ? Model.News_Date.Value.ToString("d") : "")`