# formatexception when i use datetime class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, formatexception

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project using entity framework 6, I have a property for the Date and Time and his type is"DateTime", but I have an FormatException on the converting to datetime statement.

Comment: To help you we will need more information. Please share the full error and a snippet of the code you think is causing the problem.

Comment: This is a method that i built in a particular model view and i used it in a controller to convert the type from string to datetime
--------------
"public DateTime GetDateTime()
        {
            return Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));

        }"

Comment: you can get a solution from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041179/extracting-just-date-from-returned-date-and-time-by-sql-server-to-show-in-web-pa). please check this

Comment: The problem is still existed after adding "        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{d MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
"
the exeption message is"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: paste some code in code snipet. proper otherwise on one can help you.